# Azure storage geo-redundancy solution for high availability of both reads and writes as well

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

To improve our application's availability, we have opted RA-GZRS for Azure storage. This enables us to read from the secondary when the primary is down, but we can't write to it.

But for our application to keep its essential service up & running, not only read also write to storage in the event of a region going down is MUST.

As there is no built-in  solution for the above mentioned scenario, is there any custom solution which enables us to both read from and write to secondary region Azure storage as well in the event of a primary region going down?

Also thought of having alternative storage account with different primary region but later once availability of the primary is restored how to sync back recent delta changes written to the alternative storage account during the primary account failure?

Comment: As @gaurav already mentioned in his answer, for Azure Storage you have user-initiated failover. If you need true active-active for writes, you would need to look into something like Azure Cosmos DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Storage provides you with the capability to do a manual failover from primary to secondary in case the primary region becomes unavailable. You could possibly use this approach to accomplish high availability.

You can read more about the manual failover here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal.

Comment: as you have mentioned it is MANUAL failover, is there option to do automatic failover programmatically or turnkey switch while setting up Azure storage account? since manual failover leads to data loss & doesn't suit for production workload..

Comment: Sorry, “manual” is kind of incorrect term for it. It should have been named “user initiated failover”. You should be able to do the failover using Azure SDK or REST API.

Comment: @ gaurav as you have mentioned, failover can be achieved programmatically as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-create-geo-redundant-storage?tabs=dotnet11#retry-event-handler. When “user initiated failover" is possible then why [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design?tabs=current#handling-updates-when-running-in-read-only-mode) suggestion? when to consider it? Confusing.

Comment: There are a few reasons I could think of: 1) "User initiated failover" is a relatively new feature in Azure Storage whereas "Reading from secondary" pattern has been around for ages (ever since RAGRS redundancy is announced). 2) It is still complicated to handle "user initiated failover" and one needs to completely understand the implications (do read the fine print [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#important-implications-of-account-failover). HTH.

Comment: Its unfortunate, time taken to failover after initiation is NOT instantaneous. With this time delay I dont see the point of achieving failover programmatically.